# Issue on Django Url Routers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I an trying to make url router in Django which supports following URLs :

- `http://localhost:8000/location/configuration`
- `http://localhost:8000/location/d3d710fcfc1391b0a8182239881b8bf7/configuration`

```py
url(r'^locations/configuration$',
    location_config.as_view(), name="location-config"),
url(r'^locations/(?P<location_key>[\w]+)/configuration$',
    location_config.as_view(), name="location-config-uri")
```

Whenever I tried to hit `http://localhost:8000/location/configuration`, it picked up the second URL routing format instead of picking up first one.

Error:

> TypeError at /locations/configuration/   get() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'location_key'

Can anyone help me here what goes wrong with the `url` routing format?

Comment: Why not this `url(r'^locations/configuration/(?P<location_key>[\w]+)/$',location_config.as_view(), name="location-config-uri")`?

Comment: @shaikmoeed I am migrating older project that was written in ruby and already running in production. I am unable to change the url structure. I have to keep the structure remain same.

Comment: I think you need to show your view `location_config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it does pick the first pattern which has no arguments, however you're using the same view in both patterns and `location_config` view has required argument `location_key` which is not provided when first pattern matches the URL. That's what error message is saying.

So write another view which will not require `location_key` argument or alter this view definition: add default to the parameter

```
def location_config(request, location_key=None):
    ....
```

now it is not a "*required* positional argument".

Answer (score 0):

django Will look for a pk when you are using a detail view by default. you have to override it by using `get_object()`

in your case

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None): 
    location_key = self.kwargs.get('location_key')
    obj = Model.objects.get(id=location_key)
    return obj
```

Comment: can you post your views.py

Comment: and try changing from (?P<location_key>[\w]+) to   (?P<location_key>[\w-]+)

Comment: sorry I can't, but the issue is on router side before reaching to the views. below error clearly states that.

Error: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'location_key'.

Comment: the error you are getting because you are not using pk in your url. if you are using anything instead of pk you have to def it in your views

Comment: what is pk ?? 

I can get location_key when I hit http://localhost:8000/location/d3d710fcfc1391b0a8182239881b8bf7/configuration
via 


# location config api.
class location_config(APIView):
    '''get location configuration'''
    def get(self,request,location_key):

Comment: add lookup_url_kwarg = "location_key"